# Domino error, SMTP: SSL bad peer certificate. Connection refused

Tags: ssl, ibm-domino

We use Lotus Domino 8.5. Currently our Domino server is able to route emails to different external domains. But very recently one of the user has changed the domain so for example `xyz@old.com` got changed to `xyz@new.com` and the user is not receiving emails when domain got changed.

When checked in domino mail routing logs we see the following error pattern for example:

```
12/11/2014 03:40:31 AM Router: No messages transferred to xxxxxxx (host yyyyyyy) via SMTP: SSL bad peer certificate. Connection refused.
```

Please let me know some direction so as to troubleshoot this problem.

Answer (score 3):

This error has to do with Poodle. Because of that a lot of providers disabled SSLV3. And Domino 8.5.x is only able to do SSLV3. So as long as the receiving server forces you to use SSL there are only two possible things for you to do:

1. Update your Domino to 9.0.1FP2IF2 - There is a fix against poodle and the support for TLS 1.0

or

2. Put any kind of Appliance before your domino- Server that is able to do TLS- encryption.

Unfortunately there is no direct fix for 8.5.x

Comment: Additional to the above make sure you aren´t the one who enforce TLS and have a fallback in place. This can be configured via the Notes.ini entry [RouterFallbackNonTLS](http://www.lntoolbox.com/en/notesini-reference/bycategory/20-smtp_configuration/110-RouterFallbackNonTLS.html)